# Write a Query based on a Query - Not Working With Concatenation

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I need to create a datasource for a combobox using a Linq to SQL query.

i.e. cboFindPerson.DataSource = LQPersonList
    (where LQPersonList is a query)

But this time, I need to first concatenate the LastName and FirstName fields, and then order by the FullName, like this.

```
'-- Create the first Query with concatenation
    Dim LQ = From b In DCAppMain.tblPeopleMain
        Where b.PeopleID = lngPeopleID And b.CurrentEmployee = True 
        Select FullName = b.LastName & ", " & b.FirstName, b.PeopleID

'-- Create the 2nd Query based on first so I can order by FullName
    Dim LQPersonList = From c In LQ
        Order By c.
```

But when I get to c., intellisense says no fields are available.

I've written queries based on queries before w/o issue.  I've also concatenated fields w/o issue.  But apparently putting the two together is an issue.

I've been searching on this for several hours now, but can't find an answer that is on target.

Comment: this is because LQ will end up being an `IEnumerable(of Anonymous Type)` and intellisense doesn't pick up any properties the way you have it set up. Try `Dim LQ = From b In DCAppMain.tblPeopleMain Where b.PeopleID = lngPeopleID And b.CurrentEmployee = True Select New With{.FullName = b.LastName & ", " & b.FirstName, .PeopleID = b.PeopleID}`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you Mike_OBrien!

Comment: Glad I was able to help! I summarized my comment in an answer below so if this fixed your issue please make sure to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
Dim LQ = From b In DCAppMain.tblPeopleMain
    Where b.PeopleID = lngPeopleID And b.CurrentEmployee = True 
    Select FullName = b.LastName & ", " & b.FirstName, b.PeopleID
```

you need to use:

```
Dim LQ = From b In DCAppMain.tblPeopleMain Where b.PeopleID = lngPeopleID And 
    b.CurrentEmployee = True Select New With{.FullName = b.LastName & ", " & 
    b.FirstName, .PeopleID = b.PeopleID}
```

this is because when you pull individual properties out of a LINQ statement you end up with an `IEnumerable(Of AnonymousType)` which is fine but if you want intellisense to pick up the values that you are pulling out of your collection of objects then you need to assign them names.

So using the second LINQ statement you are basically creating a constructor for the anonymous type that also defines the properties `FullName` and `PeopleID` on the anonymous objects that make up the collection returned by the LINQ statement.